# Pass array to function with .slice and .push together

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a shorter way of doing this:

```js
let arrSlicePush = arr.slice();
arrSlicePush.push(num);
let x = func(arrSlicePush);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `let ArrSlicePush = Arr.slice(); ArrSlicePush.push(Num);
let x = Func(ArrSlicePush);` ?

Comment: Yes, I jus write it shorter

Comment: `.push()` returns number of elements pushed+original length of array. So, you made a mistake. You didn't write it shorter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply do:

```
func([...arr, num]);
```

Worth noting that `Array.push` returns the length of the array anyway, so the first example is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You would call [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead of `Array.prototype.push`.

Also, since `concat` already merges two arrays and returns a new one, you so not even need to slice the original array.

```js
const arr = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
const num = 5;

const func = (arr) => arr.map(e => String.fromCharCode(e + 65));

const x = func(arr.concat(num));

console.log(x);
```

---

### Notes

`[ ...arr, val ]` is syntactic sugar for `arr.concat(val)`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
func(animals.slice().concat(num));
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64172427/5648954), you don't need to use `.slice()` ;)

Comment: yeah, you are totaly right, but the question was to use both slice() & puch(), since push() cant not be used so I suggested the concat().... but we dont know if the person need to use slice() method for other reasons (slice(2), slice(2,1)...)  ;)